# Change the default directories presented when opening Windows Explorer for a user?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When opening the File Explorer in Windows either just from the taskbar or when a program opens a File dialog to select files to you, Windows presents a certain set of (in my case) 7 directories (3D-Objects, Pictures, Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Videos) inside my home directory as a quick suggestion called "This PC", as seen in the following picture (in German):

[image: What I see]

How can I change these? e.g. the actual home direcotry is NOT amongst these suggestions yet I would like to quickly and without using the side scroll bar select that directory to choose further options

Comment: "the actual home directory is NOT amongst these suggestions" - Can you be more specific?  Please provide a response in English.

Comment: My user directory. The one (usually) under C:\Users\Username\ Basically the locations where all these shortcuts above are actually in, but it is obviously not the user directory being presented there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have too much liberty in customizing Explorer:

- You may add or remove folders from Quick access by right-click on a folder
  and selecting "Pin to Quick access", or right-click on a Quick access item and select
  "Unpin from Quick access"
- You may return the old Favorites folder in the navigation pane with registry
  updates that you may find in the article
  [How to Add or Remove Favorites in Navigation Pane of File Explorer in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/35873-add-remove-favorites-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html)
- You may create shortcut icons on the desktop to open `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`
  with a folder as parameter, to open that folder.
  More Explorer command-line switches can be found in the article
  [Explorer.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html).

Comment: The quick access bar of the scroll bar doesn't help as the scroll bar is always centered around the "This PC" entry and thus the quick access isn't even fully in focus. I added a picture about what part of the window I explicitly mean.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. As a workaround, you might be able to create a new folder with [Directory Junctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) to your folders and set it up as the starting folder via a shortcut to Explorer. For me, Quick access is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't "suggestions", **This PC** is a virtual folder gving access to drives, devices, network locations, & the user's Shell folders. It is one of two default locations available for **Explorer** to display when first opened. The other is **Quick Access**, with pinned & frequent folders as well as Recent files. That option is configurable in the `Folder Options` dialog.

[image]

If you want to open Explorer to another location, create a shortcut to that location on your `Desktop`.

But you mentioned your profile folder. There's already a special folder on the `Desktop` for that -- it should display with your full user name:
[image]

[image]

Although it looks like a simple shortcut to your userprofile folder, it's a bit smarter than that. If you relocate any of the folders under **This PC**, they will still display in this folder. If you want a shortcut to an executable to pin to the taskbar, use this target in the NewShortcut wizard:

- `explorer "shell:UsersFilesFolder"`